# Does germanium(IV) chloride have to be handled under inert atmosphere?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, synthesis, stability, carbon-family

I am finding conflicting information on the proper handling of germanium(IV) chloride. Is the liquid air/moisture sensitive? Does $\ce{GeCl4}$ have to be handled in a glove box?

Comment: Probably only moisture sensitive afaict.

Comment: One look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanium_tetrachloride) gives plenty of hints that this is moisture sensitive. You can use this compound in DRY air.

Answer (score 13):

At times like this, you always refer to the material safety data sheet (MSDS). [Have a look:](https://www.teck.com/media/Germanium_Tetrachloride_SDS.pdf)

> Upon contact with water or *moist air* this material reacts to release corrosive and toxic hydrogen chloride gas and dense white fumes of germanium dioxide

Please also check the "HANDLING AND STORAGE" section.